# Klockwork Error with dependency (SqliteAgent)

Tags: java, sqlite, dependencies, qnx, klocwork

Good afternoon,

I am trying to add the klockwork plugin in QNX (eclipse based) which is using Java 1.6 version (It is needed this version). I have Klockwork version 9.6 installed. But I have some problems.

The results on the internet say that we need to add a variable in the system: _JAVA_OPTIONS = -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true but it still doesn't work.

When I look for something about sql in the Klockwork installation folder, there is a file called sqlite_jni . But it is strange that it does not work because of a dependency on Klockwork when Klockworks desktop works fine.

When I execute eclipse with debug mode enabled, It shows these errors:

> Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqlite_jni in java.library.path                                                   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)                                                                                        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)                                                                                           at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)                                                                                             at com.klocwork.desktopdb.SqliteJniLoader.initDefaultLibraries(SqliteJniLoader.java:28)                                                     at com.klocwork.desktopdb.SqliteAgent.(SqliteAgent.java:21)                                                                         at com.klocwork.inforceeclipse.problems.LocalProblemsStorage.readProblemUpdates(LocalProblemsStorage.java:95)                               at com.klocwork.inforceeclipse.problems.AbstractProblemsStorage.reloadProblems0(AbstractProblemsStorage.java:186)                           at com.klocwork.inforceeclipse.problems.AbstractProblemsStorage$1.run(AbstractProblemsStorage.java:159)                                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
> WARN : [com.klocwork.licensing.LibInfo:41]: Could not determine library path:
> ERROR: [com.klocwork.licensing.FlexLicenseServer:92]: Warning: Cannot find valid loccounter (loccounter.dll)                                Exception in thread "Thread-13" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.klocwork.desktopdb.SqliteAgent                       at com.klocwork.inforceeclipse.problems.LocalProblemsStorage.readProblemUpdates(LocalProblemsStorage.java:95)                               at com.klocwork.inforceeclipse.problems.AbstractProblemsStorage.reloadProblems0(AbstractProblemsStorage.java:197)                           at com.klocwork.inforceeclipse.problems.AbstractProblemsStorage$1.run(AbstractProblemsStorage.java:159)                                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

And also It appears this dialog:

[Database dialog error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRUme.png)

Best regards and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is that klockwork is compatible with QNX 32 bits.

Secondly, the klockwork lib should be added to the path:_ Klocwork\USERX\lib\ix86-pc-win32.

That's all!

Thanks.